# How to to make a join in data frame if two columns have empty values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes with 3 columns each

```
df.A= x:1,4
      y:2,5
      Z: ,6

df.B= x:1,4
      y:2,5
      C: ,6
```

My output dataframe after joining the above two dataframes

```
df[C]=A.merge(B,left_on=['X','Y','Z'],right_on=['X','Y','C'],how='left')
```

I am only getting the 2 row values but not the first row

```
df[C]=x:4
      y:5
      z:6
```

How can I deal with these missing values scenarios with joins, let me know if you are not able to understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updating with blanks:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfA = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,4],
                   "Y":[2,5],
                   "Z":['',6]})
print(dfA)

dfB = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,4],
                   "Y":[2,5],
                   "C":['',6]})

print(dfB)

dfC=dfA.merge(dfB, left_on=['X','Y','Z'], right_on=['X','Y','C'], how='left')

print(dfC)
```

Outputs:

```
   X  Y  Z
0  1  2   
1  4  5  6
   X  Y  C
0  1  2   
1  4  5  6
   X  Y  Z  C
0  1  2      
1  4  5  6  6
```

You might have whitespace issues, where one dataframe has a single space an the other has two or more spaces.

---

I don't quite understand... You code appears to be working as expected.  Here is MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfA = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,4],
                   "Y":[2,5],
                   "Z":[np.nan,6]})
print(dfA)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y    Z
0  1  2  NaN
1  4  5  6.0
```

And,

```
dfB = pd.DataFrame({"X":[1,4],
                   "Y":[2,5],
                   "C":[np.nan,6]})

print(dfB)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y    C
0  1  2  NaN
1  4  5  6.0
```

Merge left yeilds, dfC:

```
dfC=dfA.merge(dfB, left_on=['X','Y','Z'], right_on=['X','Y','C'], how='left')

print(dfC)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y    Z    C
0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  4  5  6.0  6.0
```

Were you expecting something different?

Comment: For me it does not give the the 1st row , it only give 4,5,6 but not 1,2, , also I am not using numpy, do i need to use it ?

Comment: Also I am actually working on large data set , which does not have NaN values or NULL values , it just has empty data, when joining with two empty fields the join condition is failing .

Comment: even I am thinking the same,How can I avoid these whitespace issue so that the join will work, can I replace the data with Null values and NaN values

Comment: See if you can create a small couple of dataframes duplicating the issue.

Comment: it worked when I tried to replace all the empty values with ' ' as you did . Thanks Scott